# Closures with shorthand not working

Tags: swift, closures

I have this closure here, That checks if the first value is greater than the second and if true returns a Boolean value:

```
var bloco12: (Int, Int -> Bool) -> Bool = {

    return $1($0)
}

println(bloco12(32, {$0 > 10}))
```

But I learned that there is another way to simplify this only using the symbol **>**, like this:

```
bloco12(32, >)
```

But this code doesn't work, why?

Comment: The function signatures do not match.  `bloco12` takes an `Int` and a closure that takes an `Int` and returns a `Bool`.  Your trying to give it an `Int` and a function that requires 2 parameters and returns a `Bool`.

Comment: @vacawama interesting... in many tutorials they crate a function to do this....So The only form to use only symbol > is creating a function?

Comment: `>` by itself represents `(Int, Int) -> Bool`.  There are many `>` functions though.  There's also `(Double, Double) -> Bool`, `(Float, Float) -> Bool` but they all take 2 parameters and return a `Bool`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the `>` function takes two parameters and returns a `Bool`.  Your example didn't work because you were trying to pass `>` to a parameter expecting a function that takes only one parameter.  I've changed your example to show how you could just pass `>`:

```
var bloco12: (Int, Int, (Int, Int) -> Bool) -> Bool = {

    return $2($0, $1)
}

println(bloco12(32, 33, {$0 > $1}))  // prints "false"
println(bloco12(32, 33, >))          // prints "false"
println(bloco12(32, 33, <))          // prints "true"
println(bloco12(32, 33, ==))         // prints "false"
```